# How Azure App Service Scale Out Rules applys?

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans

I'm trying to setup scale-out rules for my app service and I added the rules as follows:

1- scale-out based on CPU usage to increase capacity by 1.

2- scale-out to certain instances count "let's say 2" every day on a specific period.

Now my question is when the second rule applies which will set the instances to count to a specific count and at that time the CPU usage increased and the first rule should apply what will happen in this case does the app scale-out or it will follow the second rule and will not scale-out.

**Update:**
At the time that the second rule applies and at the same time the first rule apply does the app scale-out or it will only consider the second rule.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is an either / or setting.

Either you scale based on a metric or you specify an instance count. When you set the instance count you disable the autoscaling.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/nb-no/azure/azure-monitor/platform/autoscale-get-started

Comment: The documentation does not say about my case I have added a screenshot to make it more clear, what I mean is at the time which the second rule applies if the first rule also needs to be applied does the app scale up or it will only apply the second rule

Comment: At the end of the article: "Disable Autoscale and manually scale your instances"

"This option disables your configuration. However, you can get back to it after you enable Autoscale again"